# dropping row containing non-english words in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I turned this twitter corpus into pandas data frame and I was trying to find the none English tweets and delete them from the data frame, so I did this:

```
for j in range(0,150):
    if not wordnet.synsets(df.i[j]):#Comparing if word is non-English
           df.drop(j)

 print(df.shape)
```

but I check the shape, no row was dropped.
Am I using the drop function wrong, or do I need to keep track of the index of the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `df.drop()` returns a copy instead of modifying your original dataframe. Try set `inplace=True`

```
for j in range(0,150):
    if not wordnet.synsets(df.i[j]):#Comparing if word is non-English
           df.drop(j, inplace=True)

print(df.shape)
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kailinh/PycharmProjects/reverseGeoencoder/filter.py", line 86, in <module>
    if not wordnet.synsets(df.i[j]):#Comparing if word is non-English
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1406, in synsets
    lemma = lemma.lower()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'                                        Does that mean I need to modify the text for synsets to work?

Answer (score 0):

This will filter out all the non-English rows in our pandas dataframe.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('words')
from nltk.corpus import words
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_csv("testdata.csv")

Word = list(set(words.words()))

df_final = data1[data1['column_name'].str.contains('|'.join(Word))]

print(df_final)
```